# Changing css color of a class using jquery using colorpicker

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I have a form which has a field which takes in a hex value using colorpicker http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

I have a div: `<div class="ooffer_resort"></div>`, the css background color of which I would like to change when I pick a color in color picker. However my script below just won't work. Please can someone help? Many thanks

My form is as follows:

```
<input name="linkColor" type="text" class="first-name" id="colorpickerField1" value="00ff00" >
```

and my js is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
        $('#colorpickerField1').ColorPicker({
            color: '#0000ff',
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $("ooffer_resort").css('background', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what does the variable hex output?

Comment: hex is the value of the color picked in colorpicker. When a color is picked, it is displayed in the text field.  ex: 0000ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like your selector is wrong. `ooffer_resort` wouldn't be likely to return anything.  Did you mean to make that an ID (`#ooffer_resort`) or a class (`.ooffer_resort`)?

Comment: @user1038814 lol happens to us all. :P  Glad I could help. :)